# Ionic 3 posting data to Mysql

Tags: php, angular, typescript, ionic3

i am new to Ionic 3,i want to submit he username data to mysql. I am using the following code, it does not show any error message, but it does not show the value submitted to api.php file. How we can use the Insert command in the following api.php file.

**contact.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>My Contact</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="data.username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
<button ion-button color="danger" round (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
<button ion-button color="primary" menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button>
</ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

**contact.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
/**
 * Generated class for the ContactPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html',
})
export class ContactPage {
  data:any = {};
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,  public http: Http) {
  this.data.username = '';
  this.data.response = '';
  this.http=http;
 }

submit() {
 var link = '../contact/api.php';
 var myData = JSON.stringify({username: this.data.username});
 this.http.post(link, myData)
 .subscribe(data => {
 this.data.response = data["_body"]; 
 }, error => {
 console.log("Oooops!");
 });
 }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ContactPage');
  }

}
```

**api.php**

```
<?php
    // Allow from any origin
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

    echo "You have CORS!";

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($postdata)) {
        $request = json_decode($postdata);
        $username = $request->username;
        echo "hello how are you"
        if ($username != "") {
            echo "Server returns: " . $username;
        }
        else {
            echo "Empty username parameter!";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Not called properly with username parameter!";
    }
?>
```

Please Help to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have done `post()` wrong. Secondly, you have done it against the provider based arctecture.Which is **very BAD**.

I highly recommend seeing the below links for learning about provider based architecture.

[**In-Depth Explanation of Providers**](https://www.joshmorony.com/an-in-depth-explanation-of-providers-in-ionic-2/)

[**How, Why, and When to Use Providers**](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-why-and-when-to-use-providers-in-ionic-2/)

Your `post()` method should be like this:

*myProvider.ts*

```
 post(url: string, body: string): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(url, body, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  //to extract data
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

  //to handle error
  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

Comment: I have copied the above code from http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/javascript/ionic3/posting-data-ionic-3-app-php-server/ and it has worked for some users

Comment: it is very simple code, so i want to make it run and do not want to make any major modifications in it. i think there is some problem in calling the api.php file from contact.ts file (var link = '../contact/api.php';) this file might not be accessible from contact.ts. Thanks for reply